# How to force VS2019 ignore exceptions inside "try" section

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, exception, try-catch, visual-studio-2019

Just installed VS2019 and noticed one uncomfortable thing: in Debug it stops ("falls") at the each exception, even inside `try` sections. How can I force it to ignore these exceptions, go to `catch` and work further?

After answer of Perry Qian-MSFT. Now I see this when I have UNHANDLED exception.

Translation: "application is in pause mode". And call stack is empty.
[image: After answer of Perry Qian-MSFT. Now I see this when I have UNHANDLED exception]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears, there're two possible ways to... not solve this issue, but at least make it less uncomfortable.

1) Update 2 from Perry Qian-MSFT

2) I enabled Diagnostic Tools while debugging and when exception appears, I just select it in the log of the DiagTools and VS shows me required line.

Answer (score 1):

> How to force VS2019 ignore exceptions inside “try” section

**First**, I agree with **dixv** and thanks for his help.

Current VS IDE can ignore specific exceptions as required.Under **Debug**-->**Windows**-->**Exception settings**

You can record the previous exception's name and search under it and then  uncheck it.

[image]

**Note**

After that, please uncheck **Just My Code** option, otherwise the exception may still be interrupted.

**Tools**-->**Options**-->**Debugging**-->**General**-->**Just My Code**

**Update 1**

If you enable that feature and also want to see the detailed info about that exception without breaking **Debugging**, you can add these code in `catch`

```
 try
{

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

}
catch (Exception e) {

    Debug.WriteLine("=============================");
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Source);
    Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
    Debug.WriteLine("============================="); 

}
```

It will show the specific info about that exception in **output** window:

[image]

More info, you can refer to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61844267/how-to-not-break-when-user-handled-exception-is-thrown-in-visual-studio-2019).

**Update 2**

When you face that situation, you can just click on **View Detail** of that exception window, it will call Watch Widow and then when you click on **StackTrace**, it will show the related error file name and related line to you.

[image]

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Really, that worked. But! Now. when I'm getting unhandled exception, VS just showing me message "Unhandled exception" and, what's main, do not show me exact place (file and line), where this exception occured. Just message and tab "application is in pause mode"

Comment: Did you find the message in output window?

Comment: Maybe I said it wrong. I don't want to get any info about handled exceptions. Everything, connected to `try-catch` debugger must "ignore". Your first answer is great - VS now do it. What's became wrong, is that when I get an exception somewhere outside `try`, VS do not show me, where I get it. I'm just getting window (updated question)

Comment: Please try to disable `Enable Just My Code` and make sure that you enable `Break all processes when one process breaks`,`Enable native Edit and Continue`,`Apply changes and Continue` under `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Debugging`-->`General`.

Comment: Was one of my first thoughts. No(

Comment: Or you could try to install [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mayerwin.DisableNoSourceAvailableTab) to clear such behavior.

Comment: Well. It helped. Partly. Now I don't see this tab, but VS still do not show me line, where unhandled exception occured. What I achieved: enabled Diagnostic Tools while debugging and when exception appears, I just select it in the log of the DiagTools and (miracle!) VS finally shows me required line. Well... at least some success.

Comment: In addition to this, when you face such situation, you can click on the `Exception Window` and click `View Details`, it will call the watch window and then click `StackTrace` and you will see the related file and related error line.

Comment: This is still an issue today on version 16.9.1 and it's horrible. The IDE should stop ONLY IN EXCEPTIONS OUTSIDE A TRY AND CATCH BLOCK. Why the hell do you even stop VS in handled exceptions, and what's worse, is that you can't change this behavior. You either stop at every single exception, even on handled exceptions, exceptions that sometimes you expects, or otherwise you turn the exception off in the debugger options and then you don't stop in THE UNHANDLED exceptions, when you actually needs to stop. Horrible behavior. Won't buy VS 2019 license.

Comment: vs 2022 also has such issue

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the debugger set to break on *first chance exceptions*, which  means it will break when the exception is thrown regardless of any code to catch it. To prevent this behavior, uncheck the respective exception types under Debug / Windows / Exception Settings.

From [Manage exceptions with the debugger in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019):

> *The debugger can break execution at the point where an exception is thrown, so you may examine the exception before a handler is invoked. [...]*
>
> *If you select an exception in the Exception Settings window, debugger execution will break wherever the exception is thrown, no matter whether it's handled. Now the exception is called a first chance exception.*

Comment: Posted few comments under 2nd answer. Maybe you can find them interesting

Comment: @AleksKeller This is a quite different question at this point, and would need some more context. What is the type of the exception, what language etc.

Comment: Any exception. C#. I'm not sure whether it depends on this, because I have VS2017 and VS2010, in which this project works fine - they ignore try-catch, and point me on unhandled exceptions.

Comment: @AleksKeller There should be *something* in the call stack any time execution breaks into the debugger. If your call stack window does indeed show nothing at all, you may have some weird settings under Tools / Options / Debugging, but it's hard to second guess what. Also look into the output window and see if it shows anything relevant there.