# VS2019 always stops at raised errors in Python, even if they are disabled in the Exceptions window

Tags: python, visual-studio, debugging

I can't figure out a way to stop Visual Studio 2019 to not stop on raised exceptions (handled in code). The Python exceptions are disabled in Exception Settings. Does anyone know a way to do this?

[image: VS 2019 Exception Settings with all Exceptions unchecked stopping at a thrown but handled Exception]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to not break when user handled exception is thrown in visual studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61844267/how-to-not-break-when-user-handled-exception-is-thrown-in-visual-studio-2019)

Comment: No, that options is for native code debugging only (or .NET too I think),

Answer (score 0):

I actually think these are 1st chance exceptions and weren't handled.
VS2022 has a nice "Force Run to Cursor" which will not stop at first-chance exceptions.